# Put file name into list if it contains a certain number

Tags: c#

I'm starting to write a downloader.. But I want to put the files that need to extract, are required, or option in a list for later reference by the downloader.

A sample string that is fed into it would be like this:

```
file0.txt:0 file1.txt:0 file2.txt:1 file3.txt:2 file4.txt:2 file5.txt:2
```

What i want to do, is get an output like this:

> Extract: file0.txt file1.txt
>
> Required: file2.txt
>
> Optional: file3.txt file4.txt, file5.txt

But I have no clue how to go about doing this.
The downloader will use these lists to download files the external app needs.

Comment: Can you explain the rules you use to determine which file is in which category? It's not clear from what you've posted.

Comment: @stuartd I think suffix `0` is to extract `1` is required and `2` is optional

Comment: If the file contains :0 in the list, it will be put in the extract list, and so on.

Comment: "I have no clue" is not a question. Are you looking for help reading a file? Splitting a string? Turning on your computer? Please add more details, and explain exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: Oh you beat me to it @TheVillageIdiot

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code writing service ; you have to try something and come back with what you tried/didn't work (in the meantime here's an int you should look/search info on `string.Split`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the numbers that come after each file name are supposed to indicate what kind of file they are?

Now you definitely should try to solve this problem yourself - because thats how you learn, but here is a fairly elegant LINQ solution that creates an output identical to the example you posted.

```
// Define this in your class
enum FileType : byte
{
    Extract = 0,
    Required = 1,
    Optional = 2,
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "file0.txt:0 file1.txt:0 file2.txt:1 file3.txt:2 file4.txt:2 file5.txt:2";

    // create list of files
    var list = input.Split(' ').Select(file =>
    {
        var spl = file.Split(':');
        var type = (FileType)Enum.Parse(typeof(FileType), spl[1]);
        return new { Name = spl[0], Type = type };
    }).ToArray();

    // group by type and write to console
    var group = list.GroupBy(l => l.Type);
    foreach (var g in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", g.Key, String.Join(",", g.Select(a => a.Name)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is two string split operations on the string you're fed.

```
var input = "file0.txt:0 file1.txt:0 file2.txt:1 file3.txt:2 file4.txt:2 file5.txt:2";

// gets each pairing
var filePairs = input.split(new[] {' '});

foreach(var filePair in filePairs)
{
  var fileInfo = filePair.split(new[] {';'}); // [file0.txt, 0]
  var fileName = fileInfo[0]; // file0.txt
  var fileKeep = fileInfo[1]; // 0, 1, or 2.
}
```

From here you can do what you wish with the info you have in the `foreach` loop. And you can add the info to a list for storing it.